# R calculate averages by group with uneven categorical data

Tags: r, dplyr, average

I want to calculate averages for categorical data. My data is in a long format, and I do not understand why I am not succeeding.
Here is an example (imagine it as individual participants, indicated by id, picking different options, in this example m_ex):

```
id <- (1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
m_ex <- ("a","b","c","b","a","b","c","b","a","a","c")
df <- data.frame(id , m_ex)
print (df)
```

I want to calculate averages for m_ex. That is, the average times specific m_ex are picked. I am trying to achieve this with dplyr. But I do not quite understand how to proceed with the id's having different lengths. What would I have to divide by then? And is it a problem that I do not have equal lengths of ids?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

I have tried using dplyr and grouping by id and summarizing the results without much success. I would, in particular, like to understand what I do not understand right now.

I get something like this, but how do I get the averages?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nxze.jpg
[![example picture][1]][1]

Comment: Are you using the usual definition of "average", also known as "mean", that is calculated by "sum the observations and divide by the number of observations"? Because I don't see any columns in your data that look likely for an average. Averaging is a mathematical operation that isn't defined for letters like in your `m_ex` column. What is your expected result for this input?

Comment: Please also show the code you are running - your best attempt so far. Without seeing that we don't have a chance of helping with *"I would, in particular, like to understand what I do not understand right now"*.